# Is every point in an open set a limit point?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $S$ be some open set in $\Bbb C$. Are all points in $S$ limit points?

By definition, a point $z_0$ is a limit point if for each (punctured) open disk of radius $r$, the disk contains a point in $S$. Say $S = \{i, 2i, 3i\}$, it is not true that every radius $r$ around centered at $(0,1)$ contains points in $S$. So I'm thinking that not all points in $S$ are limit points.

Thank you.

Comment: Your set $S$ is not open in any meaningful topology.

Answer (score 2):

The condition of "$S$ is open" under the usual topology means that, for any $s\in S$, there exists some open disk containing $s$, but contained in $S$. Notice that, in any open disk containing $s$, it must be that $s$ is a limit point, and since $S$ contains an open disk containing $s$, it must be that $s$ is a limit point of $S$.

Note that this does not necessarily hold in every topology; in particular, this does not hold for any isolated point (i.e. a point $p$ with $\{p\}$ as a neighborhood), but, at least in any metric space, only isolated points can not be limit points of an open set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you have an open set $A \subset \mathbb{C}$, for any $z \in A$ there is some $r > 0$ such that the disk $D_r(z)$ contained in $A$.

Let $\delta > 0$. If $\delta \geq r$ then $z + r/2 \in D_r(z) \subset A$ and $|z-(z+r/2)| < \delta$. If $\delta < r$ then $z + \delta/2 \in D_r(z) \subset A$ and $|z - (z+\delta/2)| < \delta$. Thus $z$ is a limit point of $A$.

Your counterexample $S$ is not an open set because it contains no disks centered at $i$. In particular, no finite sets can be open.